# Schema @connection to a special field

Tags: aws-amplify, amplifyjs

I would like to assign configs from a table to responses.
The ID of the answer is not in the configs. In the answer there is a field called exam_id and this exam_id is the ID of the config

what i have:

```
type Answer @model {
  id: ID!
  exam_id: String!
  user: User! @connection(name: "Answers")
  cycle: Int
  user_input: AWSJSON
  aivy_output: AWSJSON
  final_scores: AWSJSON
  score: Int
  rating: Int
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}

type ExamConfig @model { 
  id: ID!
  item_count: Int
  zscore_mean: AWSJSON
  zscore_deviation: AWSJSON
}
```

what i want:

```
type Answer @model {
  id: ID!
  exam_id: String! // = TOWER_OF_LONDON
  config: ExamConfig @connection  //BUT it have to be exam_id == ID from Config
  user: User! @connection(name: "Answers")
  cycle: Int
  user_input: AWSJSON
  aivy_output: AWSJSON
  final_scores: AWSJSON
  score: Int
  rating: Int
  createdAt: String
  updatedAt: String
}

type ExamConfig @model { 
  **** id: ID! // = TOWER_OF_LONDON
  item_count: Int
  zscore_mean: AWSJSON
  zscore_deviation: AWSJSON
}
```

when i request a Answer, than i want the config in the response. 
So for every exam_id is a special config row in the config Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `keyField` of the connection annotation to assign the specific field that it would use.  If you're using Amplify, this is accomplished as noted here: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql#connection

Your config declaration could be something like:

config: ExamConfig @connection(name: "ExamConfigs" keyField: "exam_id")

Hope this helps.

Comment: INFO: name: "examconfigs"
its not allowed to use uppercase in the names i guess... so i get an error than... 

But this is working - THANKS!